# ReFS scheduled tasks?

Tags: windows-server-2019, scheduled-task, refs

Does ReFS do any kind of automated tasks (reindex, consistency check, something like that) and if so, what/where/when?

I have a Server 2019 system that locks up every Saturday at midnight due to ReFS-related processes taking up something like half the physical memory via the non-paged memory pool (i.e. the pool usage increases massively and most of the high-usage pool tags are directly connected to refs.sys when I analyze the memory dump). The rest is taken up by the "metafile" (as seen by RAMMap) - I assume it's also ReFS related but haven't found a way to know for sure yet. Between them physical memory usage runs up to 99/100% and after a short time the OS locks up.

Since the issue only occurs once a week at the same time every week, it seems likely that some kind of scheduled weekly task is running. However, I cannot find any such task in Task Scheduler, and thus I wondered if it was an inbuilt (i.e. unrelated to Task Scheduler) ReFS task.

Thanks!

Comment: You have integrity streams on? I think that is a once per week check that all copies / parts of the data are good. Then deduplication may actually use a lot of ram and runs also on a schedule, if deduplication is on.

Comment: does 2019 support dedup on Refs? however usually get-dedup job would be a good point and get-dedupschedule

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It looks like Integrity Streams is on since the Data Integrity Scan runs every Saturday - but it runs in the morning, not at midnight. Although I don't know what it's scanning since the ReFS drive and DPM folders come up with Integrity Streams not enabled when I query with PowerShell. Same for deduplication - I don't see any volumes with dedup turned on but the relevant Scheduled Tasks run every day/week. But again, they don't run at midnight on Saturday.